# Unconcrete polynomial value constraints

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, parametric

Let's say I have this general 3rd order polynomial defined:

$f(x):=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

If I have concrete constraints of x and y values, I am able to solve the parameters. For example:

- $f(0)=0$
- $f(1)=0$
- $f'(0)=1$
- $f'(1)=-1$

gives the solution of $a = 0$, $b = -1$, $c = 1$ and $d = 0$.

Let's say, though, that I do not have such concrete points of the poynomial and its derivatives, and instead a general statement, such as $0 \leq f(x) < 5$ for $x \in [0, 1] $?

Is it still possible to calculate parameters or a set of parameters that matches these constraints?

Comment: "$f(x) := \dots$" is not 3rd order

Comment: For your example, you could always have $$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\ge0$$

Comment: @pointguard0 fixed

Comment: @TheSimpliFire right, that's a good starting point! I'll see what I can do with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still cannot plug in inequations (is that what they're called in English?) into Geogebra. Maybe I'll have better luck with my calculator

Comment: The computation of the maximum and minimum of a polynomial on a compact interval is an algorithm and for the case of a cubic it can be done explicitly. The conditions translate into: (1) $0\leq f(0)\leq 5$. (2) $0\leq f(5)\leq 5$. (3) The derivative is quadratic. You can compute its roots, $r_1,r_2$, explicitly using the quadratic formula. The condition is that each root is either outside $[0,5]$ (this are inequalities in $a,b,c$) or $0\leq f(r)\leq 5$ for each $r=r_1$ or $r=r_2$ that might fall into $[0,5]$.

Comment: There are zillions of parameters that match your constraints. $a=b=c=0$, $d=\pi$ is one; $a=b=c=d=1$ is another, and so on.

Comment: I see, definitely gives me a lot to think, @spiralstotheleft

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am aware of that, but I meant to combine these constraints with actual equations as well so that I get a limited set of these parameters

Comment: When you write down those condition, you get the set of valid parameters as a union of the sets of solutions of 2 or 3 systems of inequalities on the parameters.